# Mono.Data.Sqlite syntax

Tags: .net, database, sqlite, mono

I need to use Sqlite, but there's a problem with my syntax (well that's what the Exception is telling me...), Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {           
        string connectionString = "URI=file:SqliteTest.db,version=3";

        SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqliteCommand dbcommand = new SqliteCommand(conn);

        string sql_command = "CREATE TABLE transaction (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            "datetemps TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "description TEXT NOT NULL);";

        Console.WriteLine(sql_command);

        dbcommand.CommandText = sql_command;
        dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        dbcommand.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Here's the Exception I'm receiving:

```
Unhandled Exception: Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite error
near "transaction": syntax error
```

I'm used to use MySql and it's not the first time I'm working with DataBases, but it's the first time I got that kind of problem, I just can't figure out what's the problem, why there is a 'syntax problem'.

Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Transaction* is a reserved keyword in SQLite. To use it as an object name, surround it with single or double quotes, brackets, or backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE 'transaction' ...
CREATE TABLE "transaction" ...
CREATE TABLE [transaction] ...
CREATE TABLE `transaction` ...
```

Note that brackets and backticks are not standard SQL, so quotes are generally recommended.

For a complete list of other reserved words: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that Transaction was a keyword and thank you for the keyword list's link :)